# How do I connect my mongo database to my node app with this mongoDB connection string using docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, database-connection

This is a part of my node app

```
app.configure('development', function() {
  app.set('db-uri', 'mongodb://localhost/nodepad-development');
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true }));
  app.set('view options', {
    pretty: true
  });
});

app.configure('test', function() {
  app.set('db-uri', 'mongodb://localhost/nodepad-test');
  app.set('view options', {
    pretty: true
  });  
});

app.configure('production', function() {
  app.set('db-uri', 'mongodb://localhost/nodepad-production');
});
```

Edited to

```
app.set('db-uri', 'mongodb://mongoDB:27017/nodepad-development');
```

Still the same error.
I have already created container for my node app which runs on local host but I am unable to connect it to another mongo container due to which I cannot do POST requests to the app.

This is my docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  apptest:
    container_name: apptest
    restart: always
    image: ekamzf/nodeapp:1.1
    ports:
      - '8080:8080
    depends_on:
          - mongoDB

  mongoDB:
    container_name: mongoDB
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

And the error I get when I try to register account details in my node app is

```
Error: Timeout POST /users
    at null._onTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/connect-timeout/index.js:12:22)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

What am I missing?
Basically, how should I connect this type of code with mongodb anyway ?
What's the role of 'db-uri'?

Answer (score 4):

Docker Compose aliases service names to host names.

Because you named your container running the `mongo` image as `mongoDB`, `mongodb` (case insensitive) will be the name of the host and the name by which you should refer to it from your Node.JS container and app.

1. Replace `localhost` in the URI with `mongodb`

The MongoDB database defaults to port 27017. Unless you've changed the port, you should specify this value.

2. Add the port to URI so that you have `mongodb:27017`
3. Optional but [good practice](https://12factor.net/config), refactor the app to use environment variables rather than hard-coded values.

This has at least 2 benefits:

a. Your code becomes more flexible;
b. Your Compose file, by then specifying these values, will be clearer.

See the DockerHub documentation for the image [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

See MongoDB"s documentation on connection strings [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

A Google search returns [many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+node.js+docker+Compose&oq=mongodb+node.js+docker+Compose) using Compose, MongoDB and Node.JS

#### Update: repro

I'm confident your issue may be related to the timing of the Compose containers. I believe your app tries to connect to the DB before the DB container is ready. This is a common issue with Compose and is **not** solved using Compose's [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on). Instead you must find a MongoDB (or perhaps other database) solution to this.

In my repro, `index.js` (see below) introduces a false delay before it tries to connect to the database. 5 seconds is sufficient time for the DB container to be ready and thus this works:

```sh
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up
```

Then:

```sh
docker-compose logs app
Attaching to 60359441_app_1
app_1            | URL: mongodb://mongodb:27017/example
app_1            | Connected
```

yields `Connected` which is good.

Alternatively, to prove the timing issue, you may run the containers separately (and you could remove the `sleep` function to ensure the database is ready before the app:

```sh
HOST=localhost  # No DNS naming
PORT=37017      # An arbitrary port to prove the point

# In one session
docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--publish=${PORT}:27017 \
mongo

# In another session
docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--net=host \
--env=HOST=${HOST} --env=PORT=${PORT} --env=DATA=example --env=WAIT=0 \
app
URL: mongodb://localhost:37017/example
Connected
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: app
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - HOST=mongodb
      - PORT=27017
      - DATA=example
      - WAIT=5000
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/app:/app

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    # environment:
    #   MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    #   MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
      # ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      # ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

**NB** Because I followed your naming of `mongodb`, the `mongo-express` container must be provided this host name through `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER`

**NB** The other environment variables shown with `mongo` and `mongo-express` images are the defaults and thus optional.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13.8.0-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["node","index.js"]
```

index.js:

```
// Obtain config from the environment
const HOST = process.env.HOST;
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const DATA = process.env.DATA;
const WAIT = parseInt(process.env.WAIT, 10);

// Create MongoDB client
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

let url = `mongodb://${HOST}:${PORT}/${DATA}`;
console.log(`URL: ${url}`);

// Artificially delay the code
setTimeout(function() {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
      console.log("Connected");
    }
  });
}, WAIT);
```

**NB** `index.js` uses the environment (`HOST`,`PORT`,`DB`) for its config which is good practice.

Including `mongo-express` provides the ability to browse the `mongo` server to readily observe what's going on:

[image]

Comment: Yes I did changed localhost to mongoDB:27017. Still the same error persists.

Comment: It could be (!) that your Node.JS is trying to access the MongoDB service before it's ready. This is a common issue with Compose. The Node.JS container becomes ready, tries to access the database, the database is not (yet) available and the code bails. Have a Google search for MongoDB and Docker Compose and wait.

Comment: See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/. I'm not familiar with MongoDB but this could be a red-herring but, it's worth a try if you're confident your code and Compose are otherwise good. You may prove this by running the MongoDB container outside of compose and, once it's ready, starting your app in a container too. Don't forget to rename the hosts and use `--net=host` etc.

Comment: I think you're correct regarding the point about the readiness of my mongo container. What I did now is deployed both on kubernetes as pods and now both are running and listening on their respective services but I am having issue what should I mention inside my nodeapp container's "ENV" block? As My connection string is not using Environment variables and I dont wanna mess up with the code.

Comment: With Kubernetes you've more ability to control the timing of deployments so that your database service is known to be running before you deploy your node app. If you're not using environment variables in your node app, then you need no `env` block in your YAML specs. You will, obviously, need to replace the host name for the MongoDB with the Kubernetes service name.

Comment: This is my connection string $$$ app.set('db-uri', 'mongodb://mongo:27017/nodepad-production'); $$$ and service name of my mongodb pod is "mongo"... So should I replace mongo:27017 in connection string with "mongo" ie mongodb service name??

Comment: Yes, if the Kubernetes service is in the same namespace (!) and is called `mongo`, then that is the DNS (host) name by which your service is available in the namespace. I assume you're exposing the service on port `27017` too. If not, change that to reflect the service's port. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services

Comment: I tried everything you said, still the same error. When I try to register in my app using form it tries to send post request to mongoDB and this error occurs.

Error: Timeout POST /users
    at null._onTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/connect-timeout/index.js:12:22)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)

Comment: I think I've spent quite some time on this and that your original question has been addressed. Good luck!